# Consistent probability of a statement, regardless of new evidence

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Given that we have a statement $Q$ that has some probability.

How can we show that if you initially believe that $Q$ has probability 1, this belief should never change? That is, show that if $P_{old}(Q)=1$, then given any evidence $P$, $P_{new}(Q)=1$.

I've been heavily stuck on this problem and don't know how to explicitly show it without using basic logic. Also, depending on what we define $Q$ as, won't there be at least one new possible piece of evidence that WILL, in fact, change the probability of $Q$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please format your posts using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: 'without using basic logic'? Seriously?

Comment: $P(Q)=1$ implies $P(Q|A)=\frac {P(Q\cap A)} {P(A)}=\frac {P(A)} {P(A)}=1$ for any $A$.

Comment: Strange question.   What has belief got to do with it?  For example Trump believes tat illigal immigrants have a high impact on crime.  Statistics show that citizens have a much higher crime rate.  That doesn't seem to matter to Trump.